# Typeclass constraints, polymorphism and cassava-conduit

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, conduit

While playing with Haskell and *conduit*, I came across a behavior that I have a hard time explaining. First let me list all the modules and language extensions that need to be loaded to reproduce my problem:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}

import Conduit                         -- conduit-combinators
import Data.Csv                        -- cassava
import Data.Csv.Conduit                -- cassava-conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS -- bytestring
import Data.Text (Text)                -- text
import Control.Monad.Except            -- mtl
import Data.Foldable
```

First I created the most general CSV parsing conduit:

```
pipeline :: (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromRecord a)
         => ConduitM BS.ByteString a m ()
pipeline = fromCsv defaultDecodeOptions NoHeader
```

Then, I wanted to output the number of elements in each row of my csv file - I know this is kind of silly and useless and that there are a billion other ways of doing this kind of things, but that was just a toy test.

So I opened GHCi and tried this:

```
ghci> :t pipeline .| mapC length
```

As expected, this did not work because the constraint `FromRecord a` doesn't guarantee that `a` is `Foldable`. So I defined the following conduit:

```
pipeline2 :: (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromField a)
          => ConduitM BS.ByteString [a] m ()
pipeline2 = fromCsv defaultDecodeOptions NoHeader
```

This is a legal definition because `FromField a => FromField [a]` is an instance of `FromRecord` according to the *cassava* documentation.

At this point, I am happy and hopeful because `[]` is an instance of `Foldable`. So, once again, I open GHCi, and I try:

```
ghci> :t pipeline2 .| mapC length
```

But I get:

```
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Could not deduce (FromField a0) arising from a use of ‘pipeline2’
      from the context: MonadError CsvParseError m
        bound by the inferred type of
                 it :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
        at <interactive>:1:1
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
      These potential instances exist:
        instance FromField a => FromField (Either Field a)
          -- Defined in ‘cassava-0.4.5.0:Data.Csv.Conversion’
        instance FromField BS.ByteString
          -- Defined in ‘cassava-0.4.5.0:Data.Csv.Conversion’
        instance FromField Integer
          -- Defined in ‘cassava-0.4.5.0:Data.Csv.Conversion’
        ...plus 9 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.|)’, namely ‘pipeline2’
      In the expression: pipeline2 .| mapC length
```

So my understanding is that my `pipeline2` is not enough specified.

But now if I try to forge a trivial conduit with an (almost) identical type:

```
pipeline3 :: (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromField a)
          => ConduitM a [a] m ()
pipeline3 = awaitForever $ \x -> yield [x]
```

Again I open up GHCi and try:

```
ghci> :t pipeline3 .| mapC length
```

This time I get:

```
pipeline3 .| mapC length
  :: (FromField a, MonadError CsvParseError m) => ConduitM a Int m ()
```

So this time, GHCi understands that I don't have to specify even further the definition of `pipeline3`.

So my question: why is there a problem with `pipeline2`? is there a way to define the most generic "pipeline" without further specifying the type of the output of the conduit?
I thought that a list of `FromField` objects would be enough.

It feels like I am missing an important point about typeclasses and how to compose functions, or here Conduit objects, in a polymorphic manner.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you got...

```
 • Could not deduce (FromField a0) arising from a use of ‘pipeline2’
  from the context: MonadError CsvParseError m
    bound by the inferred type of
             it :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
    at <interactive>:1:1
  The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

... says that `a0` is ambiguous, which makes it impossible to figure out which instance of `FromField` should be used. What makes it ambiguous? The error message also mentions the inferred type of your expression:

```
it :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
```

There is no `a0` in this type. That leads to ambiguity, because there is no specialisation of this type that can specify the `FromField` instance -- there isn't enough material for the type checker to work with. In your third example, on the other hand...

```
pipeline3 .| mapC length
  :: (FromField a, MonadError CsvParseError m) => ConduitM a Int m ()
```

... the type of the field does show up in the overall type, and so the ambiguity is averted.

It is worth emphasising that there is nothing wrong with `pipeline2` per se. The problem only arises because `length` eliminates useful information from the overall type. In contrast, this, for instance, works just fine:

```
GHCi> :t pipeline2 .| mapC id
pipeline2 .| mapC id
  :: (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromField a) =>
     ConduitM BS.ByteString [a] m ()
```

In order to use `pipeline2` with `length`, you need to specify the type of the field through a type annotation:

```
GHCi> -- Arbitrary example.
GHCi> :t (pipeline2 :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString [Int] m ()) .| mapC length
(pipeline2 :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString [Int] m ()) .| mapC length
  :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
```

Alternatives to the annotation include using the `TypeApplications` extension (credit to ben's answer for reminding me of that)...

```
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications 
GHCi> :t pipeline2 @_ @Int .| mapC length
pipeline2 @_ @Int .| mapC length
  :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
```

... and specifying the field type through a proxy argument.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}

import Data.Proxy
-- etc.

rowLength :: forall m a. (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromField a)
    => Proxy a -> ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
rowLength _ = p2 .| mapC length
    where
    p2 :: (MonadError CsvParseError m, FromField a)
        => ConduitM BS.ByteString [a] m ()
    p2 = pipeline2
```

```
GHCi> :t rowLength (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
rowLength (Proxy :: Proxy Int)
  :: MonadError CsvParseError m => ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()
```

Answer (score 2):

`pipeline3` is a conduit typed like `ConduitM a [a] m ()` (ignoring the constraints for now). So when you map `length` over it you get `ConduitM a Int m ()`; the `a` is still there in the first type parameter, and so the `FromField a` constraint can remain, waiting to be instantiated at usage sites.

`pipeline2` is a conduit typed like `ConduitM BS.ByteString [a] m ()`. Now if you map `length` over it you would get `ConduitM BS.ByteString Int m ()`. There's no `a` anywhere that type, so the `FromField a` instance can't be chosen at usage sites. Instead it has to be chosen immediately. But nothing in `pipeline2 .| mapC length` says what `a` should be. That's why it's complaining that `a` is ambiguous.

As far as I can tell (not intimately familiar with conduits), that should be the only problem with your first definition as well. `FromRecord` doesn't guarantee `Foldable`, but it has instances that are `Foldable`; you just need to pin down the type being used because `length` won't do it. You could use an expression signature on `pipeline` when you use it, the `TypeApplication` extension, a less polymorphic definition (which doesn't need to be a reimplement like `pipeline2`; you could have `pipeline' = pipeline` if you had the right signature on `pipeline'`).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of `TypeApplications`. I lifted that for my answer.